reCaptcha V2 Still getting spammed... GGRRRRR
I am having an issue with my reCaptcha v2 still allowing spam. I generally get about 1 a day up until a few days ago and just over this weekend I got 75 spam messages. I have gone through every post I can find on this site and many others and can't seem to find a fix for this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You very much.
Form submit:
    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MYSITE-KEY" data-callback="verifyRecaptchaCallback" data-expired-callback="expiredRecaptchaCallback"></div>
                            <input class="form-control d-none" data-recaptcha="true" required data-error="Please complete the Captcha">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

Contact PHP
    <?php

require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

$from = 'Contact form <EMAIL>';

$sendTo = 'Contact form <EMAIL>';

$subject = 'New message from Customer';

$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'need' => 'Need', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message', 'tel' => 'Telephone Number' , 'add' => 'Address' , 'comp' => 'Company Name', 'product' => 'Product'); 

$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon! <br> You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. If not, click <a href="Return to site">Here.</a>.';

header( "refresh:5;url=http://www..php" );

$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

$recaptchaSecret = 'SECRET-KEY';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        
        
        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }
  
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());
        
        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }
        
        $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }
    
$customerEmail = filter_var($_POST['email'] ?? null, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


if (!filter_var($customerEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $customerEmail = null; // Invalid email, set to null
}


$headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
);


if ($customerEmail) {
    $headers[] = 'Reply-To: ' . $customerEmail;
}

        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

Contact JS
    $(function () {

    window.verifyRecaptchaCallback = function (response) {
        $('input[data-recaptcha]').val(response).trigger('change')
    }

    window.expiredRecaptchaCallback = function () {
        $('input[data-recaptcha]').val("").trigger('change')
    }

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact-us.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});


Thank you aynber for the edit, I can never get the code to post correctly.

Using the code fences (triple `) before and after the code blocks are the best way to format the code. You don't have to worry about indentation

So what happens when you test it? Do you get an error? Warning? Unexpected behaviour? You need to provide some debugging info so we can understand where things start to go wrong. Agree it's not immediately obvious just from staring at the code. Debug carefully, line by line if necessary

no errors or warnings at all, it seems to work just fine aside from the fact that over this weekend I got 151 spam emails. Figured I have to have something in the syntax that is incorrect but I don't know enough to spot it.

That's why you need to test it line by line, then, checking relevant variable values, code paths etc compared to what you expected to happen at that point. We don't have access to your environment and can't do that for you. If, having done that investigation, you can define a clearer problem than "doesn't work" then we might reach a point where we can meaningfully help you.

If your tests all pass then you have to start to assume that your test cases aren't adequate to cover all the possibilties. You could also add some detailed logging into the live system so you can follow a specific run of the PHP script coming from the outside and see what it did, and what data values were involved - which might then give you a clue about how/why things are getting past the captcha.
